# embend a RInside c++ application under linux

Tags: r, deployment, shared-libraries, rinside

I developed an application whose main graphical outputs relie on R through the very useful RInside. I would like to "deploy" my application under linux systems without having to systematically install R and the needed packages. For that purpose I simply copied all the R directory /usr/lib/R, all the needed .so library and set R_HOME variables to the correct path.
However, I get when executing:

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
Execution halted
```

While RInside is in the directory $R_HOME/site-library/RInside. I guess that I have more to do (and that my approach was quite naive). Does anyone already tries such a task and can help on what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to install the other dependencies as well -- and [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) is needed to convert data seamlessly between R and C++.

Comment: Yes but the question is more how can I configure the all thing without "installing" but by simply using copy/paste of the R directory ?

Comment: You seem to be under the misconception that R installations are limited to a single directory tree.  They are not.  Moreover, nothing in the R documentation suggests that copying an entire existing installation as a valid way to reinstall.